# Permission Denied error while using npm install in Gitlab

Tags: node.js, gitlab, npm-install

I am trying to clone a repo in GITLAB related to Dialogflow project using HTTPS url. I am able to successfully clone it.
When using npm i /npm install ,I face the following error below:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I referred few articles/few posts and created SSH keys.Still facing this issue.

Please find the package.json below:

```
  {
      "name": "webhook-boilerplate",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "xxx",
      "email": "support.xxx",
      "license": "Apache License 2.0",
      "main": "server.ts",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack --mode development --env development",
        "build": "webpack --mode production --env production",
        "watch": "nodemon dist/bundle.js",
        "test": "jest"
      },
      "jest": {
        "preset": "ts-jest",
        "testTimeout": 5000,
        "collectCoverage": true,
        "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
          "node_modules",
          "fallback-one.ts",
          "fallback-two.ts",
          "fallback-three.ts",
          "repeat.ts",
          "tag-mapper.ts",
          "webhook/lib/database/index.ts",
          "default-tag.ts",
          "webhook/intent-library/actions/default.ts",
          "webhook/intent-library/intents/default-welcome-intent.ts",
          "webhook/handler-v3/example/index.ts",
          "webhook/handler-v3/example/logic/example-logic.ts",
          "webhook/intent-library/action-mapper.ts",
          "webhook/intent-library/intent-mapper.ts",
          "webhook/intent-library/webhook-controller.ts",
          "webhook/lib/dialogflow-fulfillment-builder-v3/index.ts",
          "webhook/lib/http/index.ts",
          "error-handler.ts",
          "validation-error.ts",
          "request-validator.ts",
          "api-helper.ts",
          "webhook/handler-v3/tags/index.ts",
          "webhook/helper/basic-auth.ts",
          "webhook/app.ts",
          "lib/logger/index.ts"
        ]
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=6.0.0"
      },
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/xxx/xxx/"
      },
      "issues": {
        "url": "https://github.com/xxx/xxx/"
      },
      "homepage": "https://github.com/xxx/xxx/",
      "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/firestore": "^3.3.3",
        "ajv": "^6.12.3",
        "axios": "^1.1.3",
        "dialogflow-fulfillment-builder": "github:xxx/dialogflow-fulfillment-builder",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
        "express": "^4.16.3",
        "express-winston": "^4.0.1",
        "handlebars": "^4.7.6",
        "hash-generator": "^0.1.0",
        "helmet": "^3.21.2",
        "jest": "^29.3.1",
        "nodemailer": "^6.4.11",
        "pdf-creator-node": "^1.4.1",
        "puppeteer": "^5.3.0",
        "request": "^2.88.2",
        "request-promise": "^4.2.5",
        "winston": "^3.0.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@jest/globals": "^29.3.1",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
        "@types/jest": "^29.2.3",
        "@types/node": "^17.0.35",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
        "supertest": "^6.3.1",
        "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
        "ts-loader": "^9.3.0",
        "typescript": "^4.9.3",
        "webpack": "^5.72.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
        "webpack-shell-plugin-next": "^2.2.2"
      },
      "keywords": [
        "webhook framework",
        "dialogflow webhook",
        "virtual agent",
        "boilerplate",
        "dialogflow boilerplate",
        "fulfillment service"
      ]
    }
```

Could you please help me out? Let me know if I need to add more details to the question.